# "I used a pen to write this letter" and similar constructions

Tags: grammar

Would this be a suitable translation?:

> Ich habe einen Stift benutzt diesen Brief zu schreiben.

These sentences confuse me because (if my grammar understanding is correct) there are 2 direct objects.

Is there a general way to write "used _ to _" type sentences?

**Edit**: An even more complex example (possibly) - "Can I use this pen to write the letter?". Would this be a suitable translation?

> Kann ich diesen Stift benutzen einen Brief zu schreiben?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8410/word-meaning-to-use-verwenden-anwenden-benutzen-nutzen-gebrauchen and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/a-used-for-structure-in-german - (used to *vs.* used for)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The translations are fine, except that you're missing an *um* (the "to" in "use X to Y"):

> Ich habe einen Stift benutzt, **um** diesen Brief zu schreiben.
>
> Kann ich diesen Stift benutzen, **um** einen Brief zu schreiben?

----> Below is Wolfgang's edit:

Bei dem Teil

> ..., um diesen Brief zu schreiben

handelt es sich um eine erweiterte Infinitivgruppe (wegen dem **zu schreiben,** was nur in erweiterten Infinitivgruppen vorkommt) was in diesem Beispiel als Kausalergänzung (Satzglied) fungiert. Ein **um ... zu** + Infinitiv ist auch eine sehr gebräuchliche Satzkonstruktion im Deutschen, um eine Kausalergänzung zu bilden.

> Der Mörder versteckte die Mordwaffe, **um** die Polizei auf die falsche Fährte **zu** führen.
>
> Der Mörder versteckte die Mordwaffe, **um** frei**zu**kommen. (freikommen ist hier der Infinitiv)

Auch kann man die Frage bilden und sich dabei die englischen Übersetzungen betrachten, damit es klarer wird.

> Warum habe ich einen Stift benutzt? Ich habe einen Stift benutzt, **um** diesen Brief zu schreiben
>
> Why did I use a pen? I used a pen because I wrote this letter. / I used a pen to write this letter.

Im Englischen wird die zweite Form wesentlich öfter verwendet als die erste. Im Deutschen gibt es eine solche Verkürzung und Weglassen von Bindewörtern und Präpositionen im korrekten Deutsch (außer vielleicht bei örtlichen Dialekten, die meist mit Migrationshintergrund gesprochen werden) nicht. Daher ist das Weglassen des **um** in diesem Fall auch ein schwerer grammatikalischer Fehler.

Comment: An _um_ is possible, but not required.

Comment: The `um` would be the normal use case. Omitting it is a very high register of language, even in formal written language.

Comment: `Den Brief zu schreiben nutzte ich den Stift`. Mir scheint, bei Sätzen ohne `um` kehrt man die Satzteile gern um. `Ich nutzte den Stift, den Brief zu schreiben`

Comment: @chrlu Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Toscho Same question as above. Do you have a reference that states if and when the 'um' can be omitted?

Comment: @divby0 Nein, weil ich kein Fachmann bin und deswegen keine einschlägige Fachliteratur kenne, die diese Frage abdeckt.

Comment: @WolfgangStelzhammer Wäre es nicht treffeneder, dass *um* mit *in order to* anstatt mit *because* zu übersetzen (letztes Beispiel). Ich denke, dass dies eine präzisere Übersetzung ist und man die Parallele auch ziehen sollte.

Answer (score 2):

In your sentences, there is only one object to *benutzen*; namely, *einen Stift* or *diesen Stift*. The other accusative (*diesen Brief/einen Brief*) is governed by the infinitive instead, *schreiben*.

“Ich habe diesen Stift benutzt” is already a complete sentence. You extended it with an infinitive construction giving a purpose, which is fine. (Often, *um* is used to introduce it; in that case, a comma becomes mandatory, whereas in your version it is optional.) There are other means to express the purpose, too:

> Ich habe für diesen Brief einen Stift benutzt.
>   Ich habe für das Verfassen dieses Briefs einen Stift benutzt.
>   Kann ich diesen Stift dazu benutzen, einen Brief zu schreiben?

(Note: If you are asking for permission, because you are borrowing the pen, you would rather use *dürfen* instead of *können*.)

Answer (score 1):

Ich finde, "ich habe einen Stift benutzt, um den Brief zu schreiben" klingt komisch, vielleicht etwas umständlich. Ich würde sagen "ich habe diesen Brief mit einem Stift geschrieben".

Comment: Das ist aber eine andere Aussage, mit zufällig gleichem Ergebnis. "Womit hast du den Brief geschrieben? - Ich habe diesen Brief mit einem Stift geschrieben." vs "Wofür brauchstest du den Stift? - Ich habe den Stift benutzt, um einen Brief zu schreiben."

Comment: Ok, richtig, es kann eine leicht unterschiedliche Aussage sein, je nach Kontext. Auf "Wofür brauchstest du den Stift?" würde ich auch nur mit "Um einen Brief zu schreiben" antworten, und dadurch fällt die Konstruktion mit benutzen weg, die ich umständlich finde.

Comment: Als Übersetzung des Beispiels gefällt mir **"mit"** viel besser, als ein *"um zu"* Konstrukt (in das man leicht vefällt, wenn man **"to"** meint übersetzen zu müssen).